# Continue function after load image

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am beginner in JS. I have a function to lazy load images in bootstrap carousel. How can I do to continue this function after image is loaded?

```
$("#slider").on("slid.bs.carousel", function()
{
    var nextItem = $("#slider").find("div.active").next(".item");
    if(!nextItem.length)
    {
        nextItem = $(".active.item").siblings(":first");
    }
    var nextImage = nextItem.find("img");
    if(nextImage.hasClass("lazy-load"))
    {
        var src = nextImage.attr("data-src");
        nextImage.removeClass("lazy-load");
        nextImage.attr("src", src);
    }

    //the following code must be executed after nextImage is loaded:

    clearTimeout(t);

    $("#slider").carousel("pause");

    var duration = $(this).find("div.active").attr("data-interval");
    t = setTimeout(function() { $("#slider").carousel({interval: 1000}); }, duration-1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just wait for the onload event:

```
$("#slider").on("slid.bs.carousel", function()
{
    var that = this;
    var nextItem = $("#slider").find("div.active").next(".item");
    if(!nextItem.length)
    {
        nextItem = $(".active.item").siblings(":first");
    }
    var nextImage = nextItem.find("img");
    if(nextImage.hasClass("lazy-load"))
    {
        var src = nextImage.attr("data-src");
        nextImage.removeClass("lazy-load");
        nextImage.attr("src", src);
    }

    //the following code must be executed after nextImage is loaded:
    $(nextImage).on("load",function(){
        clearTimeout(t);

        $("#slider").carousel("pause");

        var duration = $(that).find("div.active").attr("data-interval");
        t = setTimeout(function() { $("#slider").carousel({interval: 1000}); }, duration-1000);
    });

});
```